# get < image> src php to display in html

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is my javascript  code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.aire-force,.army').click(function() {  
                var storedData;                             
                var qString = 'categorie=' +$(this).text();
                $.post('getimage.php', qString, processResponse);
    });

    function processResponse(data) {
                $('.results').html(data);
                storedData = data;
                alert(storedData);
                document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = test;
    }


});
```

and this my file PHP (getimage.php):

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if(!$con) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }
mysql_select_db("DB", $con);
$categorie = $_POST['categorie'];

$q = "SELECT title from designs  WHERE  categorie='$categorie'";

$r = mysql_query($q);

while( $array = mysql_fetch_array($r)){

      echo $array['title'];
} 
?>
```

and i need to get the tile of image in my code HTML :

```
require_once('getimage.php');
<img  src="images/ echo $array['title']; />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
require_once('getimage.php');
< img  src="images/ echo $array['title']; />
```

Should be replaced by:

```
<?php include('getimage.php'); ?>
<img src="images/<?php echo $array['title']; ?>" />
```

This should work.. Save this html file also as a .php ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = test;
```

You never set **test** variable.